# Collapsing a data.frame to a data.frame -- problems with by() and aggregate()

Tags: r

Consider that I have the following data and function returning summary statistics that I like

```
landlines <- data.frame(
                year=rep(c(1990,1995,2000,2005,2010),times=3),
                country=rep(c("US", "Brazil", "Asia"), each=5),
                pct =  c(0.99, 0.99, 0.98, 0.05, 0.9,
                         0.4,  0.5,  0.55, 0.5,  0.45,
                         0.7,  0.85, 0.9,  0.85, 0.75)
                )
someStats <- function(x)
{
  dp <- as.matrix(x$pct)-mean(x$pct)
  indp <- as.matrix(x$year)-mean(x$year)
  f <- lm.fit( indp,dp )$coefficients
  w <- sd(x$pct)
  m <- min(x$pct)
  results <- c(f,w,m)
  names(results) <- c("coef","sdev", "minPct")
  results
}
```

I can apply that function to a data subset successfully like this:

```
> someStats(landlines[landlines$country=="US",])
      coef      sdev    minPct 
 -0.022400  0.410938  0.050000
```

or look at a breakdown by country like this:

```
> by(landlines, list(country=landlines$country), someStats)
country: Asia
      coef       sdev     minPct 
0.00200000 0.08215838 0.70000000 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
country: Brazil
      coef       sdev     minPct 
0.00200000 0.05700877 0.40000000 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
country: US
     coef      sdev    miPct 
-0.022400  0.410938  0.050000
```

Trouble is, that is not the `data.frame` object I need for further processing, and it won't cast as such:

```
> as.data.frame( by(landlines, list(country=landlines$country), someStats) )
Error in as.data.frame.default(by(landlines, list(country = landlines$country),  : 
  cannot coerce class '"by"' into a data.frame
```

"No problem!" I think, since the similar `aggregate()` function does return a `data.frame`:

```
> aggregate(landlines$pct, by=list(country=landlines$country), min)
  country    x
1    Asia 0.70
2  Brazil 0.40
3      US 0.05
```

Trouble is, it doesn't work properly with arbitrary functions:

```
> aggregate(landlines, by=list(country=landlines$country), someStats)
Error in x$pct : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What I really want to get is a `data.frame` object with the following columns:

- country
- coef
- sdev
- minPct

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at the `plyr` package and in particular `ddply`

```
> ddply(landlines, .(country), someStats)
  country    coef       sdev minPct
1    Asia  0.0020 0.08215838   0.70
2  Brazil  0.0020 0.05700877   0.40
3      US -0.0224 0.41093795   0.05
```

Ideally your function explicitly returns a `data.frame` but in this case, it can be coerced to one easily and correctly.

Answer (score 4):

`by` objects are really lists, so you can use `rbind` in a `do.call`:

```
do.call("rbind",by(landlines, list(country=landlines$country), someStats))
          coef       sdev minPct
Asia    0.0020 0.08215838   0.70
Brazil  0.0020 0.05700877   0.40
US     -0.0224 0.41093795   0.05
```

Answer (score 3):

`aggregate` is designed for a different purpose. What you want is `lapply(split())`:

```
> lapply( split(landlines, list(country=landlines$country)), FUN=someStats)
$Asia
      coef       sdev     minPct 
0.00200000 0.08215838 0.70000000 

$Brazil
      coef       sdev     minPct 
0.00200000 0.05700877 0.40000000 

$US
     coef      sdev    minPct 
-0.022400  0.410938  0.050000
```

In cases where the output will be predictably regular it may be better to use sapply:

```
> sapply( split(landlines, list(country=landlines$country)), FUN=someStats)
             Asia     Brazil        US
coef   0.00200000 0.00200000 -0.022400
sdev   0.08215838 0.05700877  0.410938
minPct 0.70000000 0.40000000  0.050000
```

Added demonstration of constructing first column with values in rownames:

```
> ttbl <- as.data.frame(t(tbl))
> ttbl <- cbind(Country=rownames(ttbl), ttbl)
> ttbl
       Country    coef       sdev minPct
Asia      Asia  0.0020 0.08215838   0.70
Brazil  Brazil  0.0020 0.05700877   0.40
US          US -0.0224 0.41093795   0.05
```

Comment: These did not end up giving me the `data.frame` I need for further postprocessing in my actual application.  Applying `as.data.frame(t(sapply(  )))` came close but of course lacked the country column.